# qwebengineview component doesn't present in my system

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt-creator

I have installed qt creator 3.5.1, QT version 5.5.1. I have found that my qt doesn't support qwebengineview. Could you explain why and how can I add this support?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it could be fixed by installing libqt5webkit5-dev